# How to Take screenshot of other app Ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor-plugin

It is possible to take screenshot of other apps or home screen?

I need to take screenshot or listen to screen in a foreground process

I don't want to achieve this in native android

I try to use [capacitor screenshot](https://github.com/ludufre/capacitor-screenshot) but it not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask